# Internal resistance of batteries?

Tags: batteries, resistance

In one of the answers on this site, I found link to [this](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/nightlight) project. That article mentions internal resistance of batteries and cells. Where can I find data about common ranges of internal resistances for batteries? I've always heard that it's low, but I couldn't find anywhere how low is low and common resistances for common battery types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The datasheets.

For example, here is the datasheet for Duracell Plus AA (retail) batteries: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/97133.pdf

If you do some searching around on the websites of Duracell, Energizer and the like you can often find these datasheets, though they are hidden away. I found this on Farnell's website.

First page, table 1: "Nominal Internal Impedence" - 181mohm @ 1kHz.

Comment: Internal resistance and internal impedance of a battery  are different things, I've seen datasheets providing both, with different values (see A123 LiFePO4 datasheets).

Answer (score 10):

You wouldn't know it by purchasing from a department store, but battery manufacturers (like [Energizer](http://data.energizer.com/), [Duracell](http://www1.duracell.com/procell/productdata/), etc.) publish datasheets.  Look for their industrial/OEM sections.

A standard alkaline Energizer AA battery has an internal series resistance of 150 to 300 milliohms, from the datasheet [here](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/E91.pdf).  The asterisk by that number will refer you to Energizer's [whitepaper on battery internal resistance](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/BatteryIR.pdf).

Take some time to look around [data.energizer.com](http://data.energizer.com/), it's really a very good resource.